# Notepad++ with NPPEXEC plug-ins

Tags: vbscript, notepad++, nppexec

Is there anyway where I could incorporate the NPPEXEC in my latest version of notepad++? I can't seem to have the console option in my notepad++ so I could run the output of the script instead going back and forth to the command prompt.